# Problem with data transfer in WebRTC. How to send a video stream?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, video-streaming, p2p

I ran into the problem of transferring a video stream to WebRTC. I managed to create a connection, send text. But it was not possible to transfer the video stream. Here is the client code

```
<button id='start'>1</button><br>
<button id='connect'>2</button><br>
<form  onsubmit="return false;" >
    <input id='iprts' type="text" placeholder="Msg" size="40">
    <input id='enter' type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
<video autoplay id="vid1" width="400" height="300" controls="controls" ></video>
  <video autoplay id="vid2" width="400" height="300" controls="controls" ></video>
  <script src="client/socket.js"></script><!--v4.5.2 -->
<script>
var socket = io();

var starter=null
var onepart=null
var twopart=null
var peerConnection=null
var dataChannel=null
var offer=null
var offer2=null
var answer = null
start.onclick=function(){
starter=1
peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel('test');
dataChannel.onopen=function(){console.log('chanel_open!')};
dataChannel.onmessage = function(event){console.log('msg: ',event.data)};

peerConnection.onicecandidate=function(event){console.log('candidate',JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription));onepart=peerConnection.localDescription};
offer =  peerConnection.createOffer();
peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

setTimeout(asd2,100)//no callback after loading localDescription just little wait
}
var asd2=function(){
socket.emit('toserv',onepart)
}
socket.on('toclnt',function(inf){
offer2=inf
})

connect.onclick=function(){
peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection()
offer= offer2
peerConnection.onicecandidate=function(event){
console.log('candidate',JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription));
twopart=peerConnection.localDescription};
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

peerConnection.ondatachannel = function(event){
dataChannel=event.channel;dataChannel.onopen=function(){console.log('channel_open')};
//dataChannel.onmessage = function(event){console.log(event.data)}//receiving text to console, everything works here
dataChannel.onmessage = function(event){
vid2.srcObject = event.data
  vid2.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    vid2.play()
  })
}//receiving video, nothing happens. Have no idea how this function should look like, and whether it is possible to transfer the stream through the .send() method
};
answer = peerConnection.createAnswer();
peerConnection.setLocalDescription( peerConnection.createAnswer());
setTimeout(asd3,100)
}
var asd3=function(){
socket.emit('toserv2',twopart)
}
socket.on('toclnt2',function(ing){
if(starter===1){
answer = ing
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer)
}
})

enter.onclick=function(){
dataChannel.send(iprts.value)
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true,
  }).then(stream => {
  vid1.srcObject = stream
  vid1.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    vid1.play()
  })
  document.onkeydown=function(){//again there is no callback, transmission will start after pressing any key
  dataChannel.send(stream)//I'm not sure that a video stream can be transmitted through it, but through what then?
  console.log('test send')
 }
})
</script>
```

as I said, I have no idea how the dataChannel.onmessage function should look like, and whether it is possible to transfer the stream through the send method

Answer (score 2):

MediaStreamTracks are sent using the dedicated API for that which is described in [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtp-media-api).
You will need to use either addTrack or addTransceiver before negotiating your connection, see the [most basic sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/).
The datachannel API is for generic data, the one for audio/video is specialized and they work quite differently.